# Angular Web-Component created with Angular Elements overrides app-root of the Angular Shell Project

Tags: angular, angular-elements, native-web-component

I am currently trying out Angular Elements for creating web components. I have created a web component that works in an html page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav-bar title="Test"></nav-bar>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://dev-week-web-components.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/nav-bar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The web component is displayed correctly and the title attribute is set.

As soon as I embed the web component in an Angular app, the app root component no longer works. The app root component is always empty, even though it has content! If I remove the script tag for loading my web component, the app root component of the shell project works again.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>NgElementsShell</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script type="text/javascript"
          src="https://dev-week-web-components.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/nav-bar.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav-bar></nav-bar> 
<app-root></app-root> <!-- Always empty! -->
</body>
</html>
```

To create the web component I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/comsystoreply/angular-elements-569025b65c69 (german only).

The web component created with Angular Elements is the app component of another Angular project.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule,
  ],
  entryComponents: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
  }

  ngDoBootstrap() {
    if (!customElements.get('nav-bar')) {
      const navBarElement = createCustomElement(AppComponent, {injector: this.injector});
      customElements.define('nav-bar', navBarElement);
    }
  }
}
```

The Angular project for the web component contains only this one component:

```
@Component({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:component-selector
  selector: 'nav-bar',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() title = 'Web-Component';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

The nav-bar.js file is a concated file of main.js, polyfill.js runtime.js and vendor.js from the built Angular application. In the tutorials, a scripts.js file is used. I do not have this file. If I leave out the vendor.js file, the web component does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have a similar problem, I think is a webpack problem but I am not sure

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Using Webpack 5 resolves this issue! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user14649759's tip, I was able to solve the problem! :)

Webpack 5 must be used. To achieve this, I have made the following changes:

```
npm install -g yarn@latest
yarn add webpack@latest
yarn add copy-webpack-plugin@latest
```

Add to package.json:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "webpack": "^5.31.0"
  },
```

Tell Angular to use yarn:

```
ng config cli.packageManager yarn
```

The use of yarn is necessary because yarn uses the `resolutions` specification.

Sources:

https://www.angulararchitects.io/aktuelles/the-microfrontend-revolution-part-2-module-federation-with-angular/

https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/13642